# What is the reason for the conflict between the output and the output that I think should be? (C++ Map)

Tags: c++, dictionary

```
map<char, int> cnt;
string x = "StackOverflow is awesome";

for(char c : x){
    cnt[c]++;
}
```

- I know that Map has Key : Value pair, and I thought that it's storing values like,

S : 1,
t : 2,
a : 3,
c : 4,
k : 5,
.
.
.

But when I accessed like this,

```
cout << cnt['S'];   // 1
cout << cnt['t'];   // 2
cout << cnt['a'];   // 1
cout << cnt['c'];   // 1
```

Instead of 1,2,3,4

Anyone knows why this happening or I am thinking wrong?

Comment: Why do you assume that the value of a map would be an increasing number? Maybe a look at [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) helps.

Comment: `cnt[c]++;` If there is no key `c` in the map a new map entry is created: with key `c` and value 0; the value is then incremented (value now 1).  If there is already a key `c` in the map the value is incremented.  Code is doing a frequency count of the characters in the string `x`.

Comment: @Harsh Patel, The code correctly shows count of 't' as 1, and count of 'a' as 2. That is correct because there is only 1 't'  and 2  'a'   in the string. I run this program and get the correct output. (I think that both the outputs of what you expected and what you saw when you run your code are incorrectly shown in your question). Please run your code again because it works for me.

Comment: @RichardCritten Thank you so much for the explanation. I totally understood!